# Azure function conversion from project.json to function.proj xml

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

How to convert old project.json to function.proj xml for Azure Function App

```html
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
        "System.ServiceModel.Primitives":"4.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Bson": "2.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Driver": "2.4.0",
        "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.4.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the xml as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.4.0" />
        .......
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Copy all of the package information(the path and the version) from the old file to this xml. You can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages).

Comment: Thanks for the info. i am getting error  error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   for using System.ServiceModel.Description; Also error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user3744961 May I know the version of your azure function ? When you convert the project.json to function.proj, you create a new function app or just use the old function app ?

Comment: created new function app. version - 3; Runtime version: 3.0.13139.0

Comment: @user3744961 I met the same problem before and I searched for some information just now. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728279/service-model-assembly-error-with-azure-functions-v2-net-core-2-1), it seems we can just use "System.ServiceModel.Primitives" in azure function v1.

Comment: @user3744961 You can try to copy the package's dll to azure function bin folder and use #r to import it in your function (But I've tried this way before and failed).